# Spring Boot, cannot use thymeleaf in html file

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

SpringBoot maven project using NetBeans 8.1.

If I create a *html* file inside *templates* folder in *src/main/resources* and i add **xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"** to the *html* tag I have the error **Attribute with  the local name "xmlns:th" is not serializable as XML 1.0**.

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

thymeleaf dependencies are declared in pom.xml and downloaded in Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following without errors:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
...rest of the file content...`

Answer (score 0):

Mine is defined like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```